# formatNumber function fails in IE8 showing 3.3500.3500000 instead of 3.500.000

Tags: javascript, substring

I currently have a `formatNumber` function that takes a number and applies some decimal.
It is working for me in eveything except IE8.

The following example for some reason prints out: **3.3500.3500000** in IE8 and not **3.500.000** which it's supposed too.

Any idea on what could be failing here?

```
 function formatNumber(3500000)
{
    var numString = myNum.toString();
    var result = '';

    while (numString.length > 3)
    {
        var chunk = numString.substr(-3);
        numString = numString.substr(0, numString.length - 3);
        result = '.' + chunk + result;
    }

    if (numString.length > 0)
    {
        result = numString + result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: use the F12 developer tools debugger

Comment: `function formatNumber(3500000)` HUH?

Comment: epascarello > what is it you don't understand? Please elaborate on your very constructive "HUH? comment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var chunk = numString.substr(-3);` to

`var chunk = numString.substr(numString.length - 3, 3);`

AND change 3500000 to myNum in your parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

**Q** Any idea what could be failing here?

**A** I believe that IE8 javascript does *not* support a negative value as an argument for the `substr` method. I think that's the root of the problem.

That is, the first time through the loop, `substr(-3)` is interpreted as `substr(0)`, the result is that you get the entire string, rather than the last three characters of the string. That explains the result you are seeing.